# Convert MM/DD/YYYY to substrings

Tags: java

For this program the user is told to input a data in the form of "mm/dd/yyyy" and I'm trying to use the indexOf() method with the parameter of "/" to break the date string into three substrings. I cannot use .split() method. I need to just use 2 calls of indexOf("/") and four calls to substring()

I tried doing this:

```
String monthString = dateString.substring(0,dateString.indexOf("/"));
String dayString = 
dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf("/"),DateString.indexOf("/")+1
```

And many other attempts. Thank you.

Comment: You should learn how to run the code under a debugger.  Helpful for debugging :-).   Also might want to look at String.split() function for this task.

Comment: He can't use the `split()` method.

Comment: Well, you only have two `substring` calls. If you think about it logically, it comes down to finding the first `/`, grabbing the text up till then, finding the first `/` *after* that one, grabbing the text between them, and grabbing the text after. (You'll want to remember those indexes in variables.) It's unclear to me what the teacher thinks the fourth `substring` call is for. :-) I suggest keep workiing on it, and yes, definitely find out how to use the debugger built into your IDE.

Comment: Thank you TJ, i'll consider this!

Comment: For the future, let me give you an advise, take a look fo answer's time ;) because somes are copy of others written 5-10min before. also, you can vote up the answer your did not accept as they spend time for you (if they are correct for sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2 calls to `indexOf()` and 4 calls to `substring()` so your teacher is pleased:

```
    String dateString= "11/25/2018";

    int first = dateString.indexOf("/");

    String dayWithYear = dateString.substring(first + 1);
    int last = dayWithYear.indexOf("/");

    String monthString = dateString.substring(0, first);
    String dayString = dayWithYear.substring(0, last);
    String yearString = dayWithYear.substring(last + 1);

    System.out.println(monthString);
    System.out.println(dayString);
    System.out.println(yearString);
```

prints:

```
11
25
2018
```

First find the index of the 1st `/` and use it to extract the month.
Then get the rest of the string and find the index of the 2nd `/` and use it to extract the day and the year.

Answer (score 1):

Each `indexOf` method has an overload where you provide the index to search from, this allows you to find the next `/` by providing the previous index: `dateString.indexOf("/", prevIndex + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

**1 - Use only substring**

Assuming the format is always "dd/MM/yyyy", you can use:

```
String t = "30/10/2018";
String[] result = new String[] { t.substring(0, 2), 
                   t.substring(3, 5), t.substring(6) };
```

**2 - `indexOf` and `substring`**

If single digits may be entered for months or days, then you can use:

```
int firstSlash = t.indexOf("/");
int secondSlash = t.indexOf("/", firstSlash + 1);
String[] result2 = { t.substring(0, firstSlash), 
      t.substring(firstSlash + 1, secondSlash), t.substring(secondSlash + 1) };
```

Both of the above return `{ "30", "10", "2018" }`

Answer (score -1):

1. If the user can enter like `5/2/2018` you need to use `/` index : find the first one, then the second one by looking for it one after the first one :

   ```
   String dateString = "mm/dd/yyyy";
   int firstSlash  = dateString.indexOf("/");
   int secondSlash = dateString.indexOf("/", firstSlash + 1); // start search after first

   String month = dateString.substring(0, firstSlash);
   String day   = dateString.substring(firstSlash + 1, secondSlash);
   String year  = dateString.substring(secondSlash + 1);

   System.out.println(month + "-" + day + "-" + year);
   ```

---

2. If the pattern `mm/dd/yyyy` is always preserved you could just use indexes as `ints` :

   ```
   String dateString = "mm/dd/yyyy";
   String month = dateString.substring(0, 2);
   String day = dateString.substring(3, 5);
   String year = dateString.substring(7, 10);
   System.out.println(month + "-" + day + "-" + year);  // mm-dd-yyyy
   ```